# Intermediate Value Theorem related to K.

Tags: calculus

I am having problems starting this problem. I think it is because I cant visualize the k value. I am not sure where to begin and any advice is appreciated.

Link: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Btkid.jpg

[image]

Comment: The Extreme Value Theorem provides that $f$ attains an absolute minimum and maximum, that is there exists $c,d \in [a,b]$ such that $f(c) \leq f(x) \leq f(d)$ for all $x \in [a,b]$. Notice that $f(c) \leq k \leq f(d)$, so you can use the Intermediate Value Theorem on $[\min\{c,d\}, \max\{c,d\}]$.

Comment: Think of $k$ as an  average function, taking the arithmetic mean over some values of $f$. What is it bounded by?  Use the extreme value theorem, then the intermediate value theorem

Comment: Actually, it would be interesting, perhaps, to generalize your result for the mean over an interval, using the integral notion of average. The same argument should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f$ is continuous so it transform $[a,b]$ to $[f(m),f(M)]$ then for all $x_i\in [a,b]$ we have :
$$
f(m)\leq f(x_i)\leq f(M) \implies nf(m)\leq \sum_{i=1}^n f(x_i) \leq n f(M)
$$
so $k\in [f(m),f(M)]$  and then by the Intermediate Value Theorem it exist $c\in [a,b]$ such that $f(c)=k$